# Convert email into forum post

Tags: email, forum

I work as a developer in a R&D department. We use email (gmail) as a primary communication mean. Sometimes, fiddling through emails are not easy, especially when working on projects. Emails are forwared and replied and forwarded and so on. And sometimes you forget to CC the emails to certain persons.

I imagine using a webforum can make communication easier. Let's say I send an email to a certain person, e.g with subject "Project 123" and message "Let's start it", then it will be automatically created as a forum post, with title "Project 123" and message body "Let's start it". 
Each mail reply will also be automatically created as post replies, accordingly.

Is there any open source solution for this purpose? I prefer something PHP/Python based, but as long as it works, then I'm fine :)

Comment: Do you want this "forum" just for you? Or should it be accessible by your co-workers too?

Comment: An internal forum, so me and all of my co-workers can use it.

Comment: Do you need to convert pre-existing emails to "forum" format, or are you OK with starting from scratch, with only the email sent from now on visible on the "forum"?

Comment: One alternative could be [EverNote](https://evernote.com/), you can mail your notes there. But this is a paid solution.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds very much like what you need is a server, *that all of the developers have access to*, running [Roundup](http://roundup-tracker.org/).

Roundup is:

- An Issue tracker with a web interface for viewing, editing and searching issues
- a Mail gateway allowing creation and changing of issues
- The mail gateway allows issues to become "Noisy Lists" where all of the members of the list, *i.e. those that have already posted on the issue,* that are not already in the recipients section of the message are forwarded the details.
- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Written in python
- Cross Platform *can even be run as a windows service*